# Getting 'this' object in javascript without using the word 'this'

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is getting the same result as clicking on this following submit button.

```
<input id="submit_http:" class="add_submit" type="button" onclick="return dex.forms.form_ajax_submit(this,function(res) { alert('posting failed'); },function(res) { alert('posting success'); });" value="Next" name="submit_http:">
```

I was trying to do it like that:

```
$('.NextButton').click(function () {
    dex.forms.form_ajax_submit(document.getElementsByName('submit_http:'),
        function(res) { 
            alert('posting failed');
        }, 
        function(res) { 
            alert('posting success'); 
        });
});
```

But looks like document.getElementsByName is not returning the same result
as the submit button 'this'
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why on earth don't you want to use `this`?

Comment: because i cant use since it won't relate to the "submit" button but to the "NextButton"

Comment: do you check it with document.getElementsById ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only actual mistake you made was using the function `document.getElementsByName`, because it returns an array of elements (as indicated by the plural). What you need is a single element.

Either access the first element of the array by using:

```
document.getElementsByName('submit_http:')[0]
```

or use the already recommended and more precise function:

```
document.getElementById('submit_http:')
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName('submit_http:')` will return an array of elements that have that name. If you want to get your submit button, you want to use `document.getElementsByName('submit_http:')[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

While Anthony Grist is correct, in your case, since you already have an `id` for your input, you could do `document.getElementById('submit_http:')` (which returns a single element).

Answer (score 0):

generally, we use a "self" variable for this. Before the submit, do that :

```
var self = this;
```

then use "self" into your callback